# woocommerce_before_calculate_totals fires twice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Writing an addition to the site, want to modify the price in the cart. Have the following code:

```
function apd_product_custom_price($cart_item_data, $product_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['use_rewards']) && !empty($_POST['use_rewards'])) 
    {
       $cart_item_data['use_rewards'] = $_POST['use_rewards'];
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'apd_product_custom_price', 99, 2);

function apd_apply_custom_price_to_cart_item($cart_object)
{
   if( !WC()->session->__isset( 'reload_checkout' )) {
        foreach ($cart_object->cart_contents as $value) {
            if(isset($value['use_rewards'])) {
                $price = $value['data']->get_price() - 
   $value['use_rewards'];
                $value['data']->set_price($price);
            }
        }
    }

}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apd_apply_custom_price_to_cart_item',10);
```

By some reason the hook woocommerce_before_calculate_totals fires twice. if I replace the code in the function apd_apply_custom_price_to_cart_item($cart_object) with just echo 1; it displays 11 in the cart page. Can some please help?

Answer (score 4):

I forgot the link I should refer to for a solution. You can use this at the top of your function:

```
if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
    return;
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely some other plugins hooks to 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' action.

Try to disable plugins one by one and see witch one is causing this behaviour.

In my case I found that WooCommerce-multilingual plugin hooks to woocommerce_before_calculate_totals action.

So I did this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', '_wm_ponc_upte_prc', 99 );
function _wm_ponc_upte_prc( $cart_object ) {
    if ( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" ) ) {
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
            // checking if user checked checkbox (optional)
            if ( isset( $value['wm_ponc_fee'] ) && ( $value[ 'wm_ponc_fee' ] === 'yes' ) ) {
                // your calculations ....
                // and Remove your action after you are done.
                remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', '_wm_ponc_upte_prc', 99 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have removed action after custom calculations. And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I see exactly the same issue - my hooked function is firing twice, leading to the option price being added at 2x the cost. My solution was to load the product, get the price from that and then add my incremental cost to that.

function tbk_woo_update_option_price( $cart_object ) {

```
$option_price = 3.50;
foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        $item_id = $cart_item['data']->id;
        //Hook seems to be firing twice for some reason... Get the price from the original product data, not from the cart...
        $product = wc_get_product( $item_id );
        $original_price = $product->get_price();
        $new_price = $original_price + $option_price;
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price );
}
```

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'tbk_woo_update_option_price', 1000, 1 );